# EKCalendarChooser goes into 'Edit Calendar' mode, NOT choose mode. Any tips?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios6, ekeventkit

Using EKCalendarChooser in 'EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleSingle' mode, I get it to come up, but it always comes up with "Edit Calendar" mode.   This doesn't give me the ability to choose one, only to edit/rename/delete calendars.

Any tips on what I can try?    I've tried 'setEditing' set to NO/YES without difference, turning on/off the Done/Cancel buttons, I'm trying it all but keep getting the Edit mode instead.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You must not call "setEditing" at all, then you get the choose mode. I did run into the same trap.

Answer (score 0):

```
EKCalendarChooser *calendarList = [[EKCalendarChooser alloc] initWithSelectionStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleSingle displayStyle:EKCalendarChooserDisplayAllCalendars entityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:ekEventStore];
calendarList.delegate = self;
calendarList.showsDoneButton = YES;
calendarList.editing = YES; <============================(Remove this line)
```